# Minimum number of students possible .

Tags: combinatorics

In a business school there are 3 electives and at least one elective is compulsory to opt. 75% of the students opted for marketing, 62% opted for finance and 88% opted for H.R. A student can have dual or triple specialization.

What is the minimum number of students that specialize in all three streams ?

Can someone please help?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do this either, but it seems to me you want to maximize the students that take two, but not all three streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Inclusion-Exclusion we have that:

$$|M \cup F \cup H| = |M| + |F| + |H| - |M \cap F| - |M \cap H| - |F \cap H| + |H \cap F \cap H|$$

and thus:

$$|M \cap F \cap H| = |M| + |F| + |H| - |M \cap F| - |M \cap H| - |F \cap H| + |H \cup F \cup H|$$

Now, we know that $|M| = 75$, $|F| = 62$, $|H|=88$, and $|H \cup F \cup H|=100$

So, to minimize $|M \cap F \cap H|$, we need to maximize $|M \cap F|+|M \cap H|+|F \cap H|$. Or, in other words, we want as many students as possible to take two subjects, but not all three.

Now let's look at a Venn Diagram:

[image]

OK, so we figured that in order to minimize the number of students in $IV$, we want to maximize the number of students in regions $I$, $II$, and $III$

Well, for region $I$, since there are $88$ students doing H.R, we can at most have $12$ students not doing H.R, and so at most $12$ in region $i$. so, let's put $12$ in region $I$. Similarly, with $62$ students doing Finance, we can at most have $38$ students in region $II$. And finally, with $75$ students doing Marketing, we can at most have $25$ students in region $III$. So, that gives $12+38+25=75$ students in regions $I$, $II$, and $III$. And since we didn't put anyone in a region denoting students taking a single subject, that means there are $100-75=25$ students left for region $IV$. So that's the minimum: $25$

Does this method always work? No. This time we were able to have all students take multiple streams. But, suppose the numbers were as follows:

$|M| = 25$, $|F| = 52$, $|H|=38$, and again $|H \cup F \cup H|=100$

Then using the above method we would have tried to put $62$ students in region $I$, $48$ in region $II$, and $75$ in region $III$, but $62+48+75=185>100$, so that is impossible. However, when this happens, we can simply fill up the regions until we get the total number of students, e.g. we could put $25$ in region $I$, $27$ in region $II$, and $0$ in region $III$, and while this means that $11$ students will be taking H.R. as their single subject, there are $0$ students taking all $3$ subjects.

Answer (score 3):

$0.75+0.62+0.88 = 2.25$

The average student is taking $2.25$ electives.

If $x_1$ is the # of students taking one elective,
$x_2$ is the # of students taking two electives, and 
$x_3$ is the # of students taking 3 electives.

$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = 2.25\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$

To minimize $x_3,$ we must assume that $x_1 = 0$

$2x_2+ 3x_3 = 2.25\\
x_2 + x_3 = 1$

$x_3 = 0.25$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose students 1 through 75 do marketing, 39 through 100 do finance, and 1 through 38 and also 76 through 100 and also some others do HR, whatever that is. Well, that accounts for $38+25=63$ of the 88 students doing HR, so there must be another 25 doing all three subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Call the set of students specialising in marketing $M$, the set of students specialising in HR $H$ and the set of students specialising in finance $F$.. The least number of students that can specialise in both marketing and finance is $n_{MF} = |M| - (|M \cup F \cup H| - |F|) = 75 - (100 - 62) = 37$.

The number of these students that do not also specialise in HR is then at most $n_{MF} - (|M \cup F \cup H| - |H|) = 12$.

So there are at least $25$ students with all three specialisations.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be total number of students; $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are taking only $M,F,H$; $y_1,y_2,y_3$ are taking $M\cap F \setminus H,M \setminus cap H \setminus F,F\cap H \setminus M$; $z$ are taking $M\cap F\cap H$. Then:
$$x_1+y_1+y_2+z=0.75S \\ x_2+y_1+y_3+z=0.62S \\ x_3+y_2+y_3+z=0.88S.$$
To be whole numbers $S$ must be a multiple of $100$. If $S=100$, then by adding the three equations we get:
$$z=x_1+x_2+x_3+25.$$
To make $z$ minimum $25$, we must set $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$.

Hence:
$$y_1=38,y_2=12,y_3=25.$$

If $S=200$, then by repeating the above calculations we find:
$$x_1=x_2=x_3=0; z=50; y_1=138,y_2=112,y_3=125,$$
which is not suitable.

Thus $\min  z=25$.